# Changing the Android Studio default domain?

Tags: android-studio

When I start a new project in Android Studio, I always have to change the default domain name in the package name (the default is com.example).

Is there a way to change the default domain name to my domain so that I don't have to do this every time I start a new project?

Comment: Please follow this link [Change package name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16804093/4785772)

Comment: I don't need to change an existing project. I want to change the default domain name (com.example) that is used when creating a new project.

Comment: Let's see if anyone has an answer to this question...bounty started

Answer (score 1):

The package specified in the `New Project` dialog in the `Package name` parameter will be saved after the project is created in the `SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE` parameter in the file `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/options/other.xml`. The path is different on different OS and different IDE versions. Read for [Find your configuration files](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location)

[image]

You can try the following ways:

1. The classic way to solve all problems: Invalidate cache and restart
2. Close IDE. Manually change SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE. Run IDE
3. Check permissions to the configuration folder
4. Close IDE. Delete (make a backup!!!) configuration folder. IDE will start as freshly installed and create a new configuration

Comment: Say I create a project with one package name  (say `com.codeguru`) that gets saved to `SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE`, then create a new project with a different base name (say `com.codeapprentice`). Will the second one overwrite the first in `SAVED_ANDROID_PACKAGE`?

Comment: On the third creation, the package from the second case (`com.codeapprentice`) will be displayed by default